# Steam API - Game Controller Support

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm working with the Steam API to get a list of games to show a user, and it would be nice to know if the game supports controllers. Is there a way to find out if a game has full or some controller support from the Steam API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information via the unofficial StoreFront API, using the [appdetails](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#appdetails) call.

```
http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=<<APPID>>&filters=categories
```

Replace `<<APPID>>` with the numeric application ID. This will return a json object similar to this:

```
{
    "440":{
        "success":true,
        "data":{
            "categories":[
                {"id":"1","description":"Multi-player"},
                {"id":"27","description":"Cross-Platform Multiplayer"},
                {"id":"22","description":"Steam Achievements"},
                {"id":"14","description":"Commentary available"},
                {"id":"13","description":"Captions available"},
                {"id":"31","description":"VR Support"},
                {"id":"15","description":"Stats"},
                {"id":"8","description":"Valve Anti-Cheat enabled"},
                {"id":"18","description":"Partial Controller Support"},
                {"id":"17","description":"Includes level editor"},
                {"id":"29","description":"Steam Trading Cards"},
                {"id":"30","description":"Steam Workshop"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Within the `categories` key, you will need to look for two IDs. If you look for an `id` of `17`, this indicates "Partial Controller Support". If you look for an `id` of `28`, this indicates "Full controller support" and looks like this in the list:

```
{"id":"28","description":"Full controller support"}
```